# Installing Ionic 2 in windows

Tags: ionic2

When I try to install Ionic 2 SDK in windows 10 by executing below command, I am getting

> "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules.staging'"

```
 npm install -g ionic@beta
```

Any help on how this should be corrected.

Comment: Seems like permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try for installing ionic2

nodejs install,
npm install,
npm start,
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g ionic
ionic info